# How to match numbers greater than 2048 with regex

Tags: regex

I need to match numbers greater than:
1. 2048
2. 32768

My current regex for 2048 is:

```
([2-9][0-9][4-9][8-9]|[1-9]\d{4,}|[3-9]\d{3,})
```

But it is not matching 2077. Help me out here. Also I am not able to write regex for numbers greater than 32768.

Comment: Could this be an XY problem? What do you actually want to achieve? Are you absolutely required to use regex? Of course it is possible to systematically construct regexes for arbitrary numbers, it just gets tedious.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I need to write regex only sir

Comment: Please justify your usage of regex to solve this problem as opposed to the language's number parsing tools and standard numeric comparison operators/functions.

Comment: @spender We use a tool in our work environment and in that we write regex. So I need to write a regex to pass these numbers. I don't know what you're not getting here.

Comment: @nibba Regex would be a very bad choice for performing this validation, so double-checking that there are no other options is worth asking. You haven't said what flavour of regex this tool uses. You'll want to add that to the question/tags.

Comment: @spender I'm not sure about that but I think it is PCRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to systematically construct the regex for 2048 (I think you mean greater or equal, not just greater):

- all numbers with 5 digits or more:
  `[1-9]\d{4}`
- all 4-digit numbers with at least a 3 in the first place:
  `[3-9]\d{3}`
- a 2 followed by a 3-digit number greater or equal to 048 (the 3-digit number regex is built using the same approach):
  `2([1-9]\d{2}|0([5-9]\d|4[89]))`

So the complete regex for >= 2048 is
`[1-9]\d{4}|[3-9]\d{3}|2([1-9]\d{2}|0([5-9]\d|4[89]))`.

The regex for 32768 can be built similarly.

Comment: Thanks. Similarly, I've wrote the regex for 32768: "[1-9]\d{5}|[4-9]\d{4}|3([3-9]\d{3}|2([8-9]\d{2}|7([7-9]\d|6[8-9])))"   Could you please verify if it is correct

Comment: Just occurred to me that if you're interested in matching longer numbers completely (and not just their initial 5-digit substring) you should add a `,` in the braces for the digit count, like you did in the regex in your question. So the pattern for 2048 would be `[1-9]\d{4,}|[3-9]\d{3}|2([1-9]\d{2}|0([5-9]\d|4[89]))`.